# jquery ui info into html

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I'm looking to put var h  into the 360 color space into the html below.
as the slide bar moves from 0 - 360 I want that value to replace the 360 in the hsl color space-color :hsl(360, 100%, 50%). I'm looking to have the text value change color as I move the slider.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range with fixed maximum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 0,
      max: 360,
      value: 0,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
    var h = ui.value;
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Minimum number of bedrooms:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:hsl(360, 100%, 50%); font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `css` method to update the `color`:

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range-max").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
      $("#amount").css("color", "hsl(" + ui.value + ", 100%, 50%)");
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/822fogwb/)**

Comment: @wdaniel You're welcome. Please accept the answer so it helps others, thank you.